# cannot bind event to multiple <select>'s, only first child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, onchange

So I have multiple selects like:

```
<select class="new_select" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
 <select class="new_select" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

which are dynamically appended, so I have to use the `.on` event handler. 
For some reason, the following is only fired when the first select is changed. How would I go about getting it to fire for changes to all select elements?

```
$('.new_select').on('change', function() {
    alert('clicked');
    alert(this.value);
});
```

I am open to workarounds too, looking into this, it seems there is some whisper of browsers not supporting multiple selects, so i'm not sure if that is the root of the problem. Sincere thanks for any help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event delegation` as follow:

```
$(document).on('change','.new_select', function() {
    alert('clicked');
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), so each element added dynamically can fire the function.

```
$(document).on('change', '.new_select', function() {
    alert('clicked');
    alert(this.value);
});
```

For best performance, ensure to choose the parent element on which you bind your event to make it as narrow as possible instead of `document`.